# PREEMPT_RT kernel doesn't look preemptive

Tags: c, linux-kernel, scheduled-tasks, real-time, preempt-rt

I'm trying to make a device running Linux.
My system was built with Buildroot 2022.02;

Kernel is 4.19.252 (+PREEMPT_RT patch) assembled with flags

```
CONFIG_PREEMPT=y
CONFIG_PREEMPT_RT_BASE=y
CONFIG_PREEMPT_RT=y
CONFIG_HAVE_PREEMPT_LAZY=y
CONFIG_PREEMPT_LAZY=y
CONFIG_PREEMPT_RT_FULL=y
CONFIG_PREEMPT_COUNT=y
CONFIG_PREEMPT_RCU=y
CONFIG_DEBUG_PREEMPT=y
```

But I've faced a problem I can't resolve on my own...

I run my app binding it to the core (it is a very complex one, let's assume it can't be done other way)

```
taskset -c 0 ./myapp
```

the app has many threads but I have a problem with specific pair of them.

The first one is running as 55:SCHED_FIFO, it is subscribed to timerfd triggered every 5 ms (it raises the timer by itself)

```cpp
ssize_t s;
uint64_t value = 0;
while (true) {
    s = read(m_fd, &value, sizeof(value));
    if (s != sizeof(value)) {
        //wtf ?
        continue;
    }
    timer.rearm();
    measureTime()
}
```

The second one is a cycling task thread, it runs every N ms (configurable) and takes about 150 ms to complete. It is running as 54:SCHED_FIFO

The problem is, when the second task is running (calculation state), it preempts the first thread's ability to receive timer irq...
When I measure the time between two timer events I get +-150 ms difference. When my app is bound to the core, the situation appears every N ms (period of the second task). When the app has no binding the situation is random (but still present).

I've ran **cyclictest** with --prio=55 -a 0 (the same core) along with my program and it detects no latency gaps...

I've created a test app that behaves exactly the same when bound to a single core

```cpp
/*
 * scheduler test
 *
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <sys/timerfd.h>

volatile bool g_quit = false;
int g_timer = -1;

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void signalHandler(int t_param)
{
    if (!g_quit) {
        printf("signaled %d\n", t_param);
    }
    g_quit = true;
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
struct timespec diff_timespec(
    const struct timespec *time1,
    const struct timespec *time0)
{
    struct timespec diff;
    diff.tv_sec  = time1->tv_sec - time0->tv_sec;
    diff.tv_nsec = time1->tv_nsec - time0->tv_nsec;
    if (diff.tv_nsec < 0) {
        diff.tv_nsec += 1000000000;
        diff.tv_sec--;
    }
    return diff;
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void rearmTimer(int t_ms)
{
    struct timespec ts;
    ts.tv_sec = t_ms / 1000ULL;
    ts.tv_nsec = (t_ms % 1000ULL) * 1000000ULL;
    struct itimerspec itime;
    itime.it_value.tv_sec = ts.tv_sec;
    itime.it_value.tv_nsec = ts.tv_nsec;
    itime.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
    itime.it_interval.tv_nsec = 0;
    if (timerfd_settime(g_timer, 0, &itime, NULL) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "timerfd_settime: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    }
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void* timerEventHandler(void *t_arg)
{
    printf("timer thread entered\n");
    pthread_setname_np(pthread_self(), "Timer");
    struct timespec sp_prev;
    struct timespec sp_curr;
    struct timespec diff;
    ssize_t s;
    uint64_t value = 0;
    while (g_timer == -1) {
        usleep(100);
    }
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &sp_prev);
    while (!g_quit) {
        s = read(g_timer, &value, sizeof(value));
        if (s != sizeof(value)) {
            // wtf?
            continue;
        }
        rearmTimer(1000);
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &sp_curr);
        diff = diff_timespec(&sp_curr, &sp_prev);
        fprintf(stdout, "%ld.%09ld\n", diff.tv_sec, diff.tv_nsec);
        sp_prev = sp_curr;
    }
    printf("timer thread exited\n");
    return NULL;
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void* mainTaskHandler(void *t_arg)
{
    printf("main task thread entered\n");
    pthread_setname_np(pthread_self(), "MainTask");
    struct timespec sp_prev;
    struct timespec sp_curr;
    struct timespec diff;
    int a = 0;
    while (!g_quit) {
        usleep(5000 * 1000);
        int i = 0;
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &sp_prev);
        while(i++ < 0x7FFFFFE) {
            a += i * i / (i + 1);
            if (g_quit) {
                break;
            }
        }
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &sp_curr);
        diff = diff_timespec(&sp_curr, &sp_prev);
        fprintf(stdout, "calculation %d took %ld.%09ld\n", a, diff.tv_sec, diff.tv_nsec);
    }
    printf("main task thread exited\n");
    return NULL;
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    signal(SIGINT, signalHandler);
    signal(SIGTERM, signalHandler);
    pthread_setname_np(pthread_self(), "main");
    pthread_t eventThread;
    pthread_t mainTaskThread;
    pthread_attr_t attr;
    struct sched_param schedparam;
    schedparam.sched_priority = 55;
    pthread_attr_init(&attr);
    pthread_attr_setschedpolicy(&attr, SCHED_FIFO);
    pthread_attr_setinheritsched(&attr, PTHREAD_EXPLICIT_SCHED);
    pthread_attr_setschedparam(&attr, &schedparam);
    printf("evt create res : %d\n", pthread_create(&eventThread, &attr, timerEventHandler, NULL));
    schedparam.sched_priority = 54;
    pthread_attr_setschedparam(&attr, &schedparam);
    printf("rdd create res : %d\n", pthread_create(&mainTaskThread, &attr, mainTaskHandler, NULL));
    pthread_attr_destroy(&attr);
    struct sigevent event;

    g_timer = timerfd_create(CLOCK_REALTIME, 0);
    rearmTimer(1000);
    while (!g_quit) {
        sleep(1);
    }
    pthread_join(mainTaskThread, NULL);
    pthread_detach(mainTaskThread);
    pthread_join(eventThread, NULL);
    pthread_detach(eventThread);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The test app prints time difference between current timer event and a previous one. It also prints (for debug purposes) the time MainTask thread was busy for. The time diff must be around 1 sec (without any spikes)
But with my kernel I have timer spikes up to 6 seconds (for my hardware)

Is it normal behavior of RT kernel? What am I doing wrong or what am I understanding wrong about how PREEMPT_RT patch should work?

I've dug into the kernel a bit, and it seems that ktimersoftd (thread added by PREEMPT_RT patch running 1:SCHED_FIFO) is delayed by higher priority task and it does not send timer irqs to subscribers until the kernel gives him enough time. I'm not a kernel developer so I can't say is it correct behavior or not... Also, I've build kernel 5.10 + PREEMPT_RT and the kernel activates throttle mode (O_o) when running my test app and all timers go crazy

Comment: I don't see anything in the output of the _test app_ which tells me that it _behaves exactly the same_ as described. What do you see?

Comment: Besides, `man sched` says (irrespective of PREEMPT_RT): _if a thread with a higher static
       priority becomes ready to run, the currently running thread will
       be preempted_.

Comment: ah, sorry. The test app prints time difference between current timer event and a previous one. It also prints (for debug purposes) the time MainTask thread was busy for. The time diff must be around 1 sec (without any spikes)

Comment: But with my RT kernel I have timer spikes up to 6 seconds (on my hardware)

Comment: Interesting - I see something similar on a PREEMPT_RT kernel, but not on a kernel without PREEMPT_RT.

Comment: Maybe we encounter the [Low-Priority Timer Interference](https://people.mpi-sws.org/~bbb/papers/pdf/rtas17p.pdf).

Comment: Maybe. I've read about TimerShield, but it was made for old 4.4 kernel and I've failed to port it to my 4.19. I've dug into the kernel a bit, and it seems that ktimersoftd (thread added by PREEMPT_RT patch running 1:SCHED_FIFO) is delayed by higher priority task and it does not send timer irqs to subscribers until the kernel gives him enough time. I'm not a kernel developer so I can't say is it correct behavior or not... Also, I've build kernel 5.10 + PREEMPT_RT and the kernel activates throttle mode (O_o) when running my test app and all timers go crazy

Comment: I dare to say the behavior is not correct - it clearly conflicts with the documentation of scheduling, and the implementation detail of _ktimersoftd running 1:SCHED_FIFO_ can explain, but not excuse it.